# htaccess non-www does not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that is forced to non-www (by the hosting).
I have access to htaccess file and I am trying to redirect some of my pages to another domain.
The www works, the non-www (which is the current one) it's not redirecting.
Here it is what I have in htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Redirect 301 /my-slug-here https://anotherdomain.example/some-slug-here/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "forced to non-www (by the hosting)" - how? "The www works, the non-www (which is the current one) it's not redirecting." - That's the opposite of what I would expect you to say. And that `Redirect` is one such redirect? There's not a lot to go on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Redirect` from `mod_alias` and `RewriteRule` from `mod_rewrite` together is not recommended.   You will get better results by implementing your rule with `RewriteRule` and putting it above your front controller rule.

I wouldn't recommend putting non-WordPress rules inside the `BEGIN WordPress` section because WordPress could overwrite that whole section during an upgrade.   I'd put your redirect rule above the WordPress section, even if that means using a second `RewriteEngine On`

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?my-slug-here https://anotherdomain.example/some-slug-here/ [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Although the OPs rules should still "work" IMO. It looks like there is something else going on if "www works and non-www doesn't" and that "forced to non-www (by the hosting)" is a bit dubious.

Comment: Thanks for the bug fix. Put it into the answer. I took the dub dub dub works to mean that it redirects to non dub dub dub still, maybe something else is going on

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive before the first rule. In fact, it's actually a bit misleading to do so... (even though it would appear more logical and everyone does it) since it's the last instance that "wins" and controls the entire file. Setting the first instance to `RewriteEngine Off` will have no effect because it is set to `On` later in the file.

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know that.  I always assumed that needed to come first.

Comment: Thank you for non-wordpress hint. That helped a lot.
Now it works.